# VBA - run VBA code, which is stored as a string code

Tags: vba

i want to execute VBA code, which is stored as a string, i would like to execute this, for example :

```
dim code as string
code = "Msgbox ""test"""
ExecuteCommand(code)
```

Please help me to execute this . Thanks :)

Comment: You can't do this because code needs to be compiled in order to be executed. You could write this to a module, or a VBS file and then call it - but that's far more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Eval will work in Access with functions as long as the function call includes parenthesis
`code = "Msgbox(""test"")"
Eval(code)`

ref: [Eval function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa172212(v=office.11).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for answer,
It gaves me : Compile error : sub or function is not defined

Comment: Perhaps try wrapping your Msgbox call in a compiled procedure, and calling that procedure instead of Msgbox directly, otherwise, I believe Macro Man is correct..